# Looback 2.0 NodeJS synchronize 2 MongoDbs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, data-synchronization, redundancy

I need to synchronize 2 databases in a NodeJS server application using Loopback 2.0.
This problem is a result of the need of redundancy, so there are 2 servers running on different physical machines. 
Both of them have a local database, but they should still contain the same data, in case one of the servers stops working.

Both of the servers use a MongoDB. I am aware that you can define multiple datasources in the datasources.js file for Loopback, but all I could find about it was about reading from different datasources according to the used model.

How can all the information that both servers get from the users get persistet in both of the databases so they are synchronized at all times, without letting both servers process the same requests (performance reasons)?

Comment: Do not use loopback to do this. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_replication.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think this is exactly what I need. Is it a good thing to use if the secondary instances of the databases are not only used as backup, but as a productive database in case the first server fails aswell?